# Why can't I make a pull request even when doing everything from scratch?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have a few folders that I want to upload to github. These are the steps I took in order to that:

- created a repository in github.com by selecting the '+' button
- initialized git in the folder -> `git init`
- copied https link from the repo and ran the command -> `git remote add origin <https link of the git repository>`
- `git add <name of the folder I want to push>`
- `git commit -m "commit message"`
- `git push origin master`

I opened github.com to make a pull request but it won't let me do it. I have **attached the screenshots** from github. I tried this process multiples times by deleting ".git" file but the problem remains. The `create pull request` button is not highlighted due to which I can't make a pull request. Will you please let me know what's going on and how to fix it?
[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlusE.png)
[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWxP1.png)

Comment: I'm confused by the following (maybe it's unrelated and has no impact). If you created the repo on GitHub first, why didn't you just opened the terminal and run `git clone <repo_url>` instead of creating a repo locally and then setting the upstream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have only push `master`, GitHub would consider that your default branch (which, [initially, was `main` on GitHub side](https://github.com/github/renaming#new-repositories-use-main-as-the-default-branch-name))

As mentioned in [Pull Request](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests#differences-between-commits-on-compare-and-pull-request-pages)

> Pull request pages show the diff between
>
> - the tip of the head ref and
> - the common ancestor of the head and base ref at the time when the pull request was created.

But here, you have pushed only *one* branch.
There is no common ancestor between `master` and anything else (including the unborn `main` branch)

You would need to create a new branch locally, with new commits, to be able to push it, and make a PR from it.

Answer (score 0):

When sharing a locally created branch to a remote you need to use `git push -u origin master`, where `-u` is short for `--set-upstream`

Comment: I ran `git push -u origin master` and this is the message I got, ```Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
Everything up-to-date```